# Working with references in Java to create side effects

Tags: java, reference, side-effects

I'm used to working with languages that explicitly allow you to work with references/pointers, what I'm attempting to do relies upon that present.

If I have an object of class `Foo` and I have three objects of class `Bar`. **How do I have all three objects of class `Bar` reference the one instance of `Foo`?**

(I am relying on side effects)

If this is possible in Java at all (which I believe gives you a copy of a reference, but I've read conflicting information and now remain a little confused)

Comment: `bar1.field = foo; bar2.field = foo; bar3.field = foo;`

Comment: Pass `Foo foo` as argument to a method in `Bar` to receive a `Foo` variable. Then, you will have a copy of the reference stored in `Bar`, and any instance of `Bar` could alter the state of that `Foo` (if possible). If you're asking if any instance of `Bar` can replace the object reference in `Foo` for the other instances of `Bar`, it's not possible since Java is pass by value.

Comment: If you can provide a little more detail on your use case, it might be evident on what you need.  Is Foo a Singleton?  Is Bar composed with a Foo instance?  A little more help in what you are looking for can help give a better answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If this is possible in Java at all (which I believe gives you a copy
>   of a reference, but I've read conflicting information and now remain a
>   little confused)

Maybe you're used to using languages like C which treat memory as one giant array and which use pointers (and pointers to pointers) to data structures.  Java differs from C by using references (instead of pointers) and objects (instead of structures).

The analog to pointers in Java is the *reference variable* which stores a reference to an object.  The value of a reference variable is a pointer, but in Java you never use the pointer value itself, only the object to which it refers.

If you have a class defined this way:

```
public class Bar {
    private Foo fooRef;

   public Bar(Foo foo) {
       this.fooRef = foo;
   }

   :
   :
}
```

Note that `Bar` is defined to have a mutable instance field, `fooRef` which will hold a reference to an object of type `Foo`.

The following will instantiate three instances of `Bar`, each with a reference to 
the same `Foo` object:

```
Foo myFoo = new Foo();

Bar bar1 = new Bar(myFoo);
Bar bar2 = new Bar(myFoo);
Bar bar3 = new Bar(myFoo);
```

Because the instance field, `fooRef` is mutable, the object which contains it can be mutated by any method that has access to the field.  This enables the side effects you're looking for (although mutable fields are a particular concern in concurrent programming).